# What can cause "Reboot and select proper boot device" other than hard drive issues?

Tags: windows-7, windows, motherboard, power-supply, hardware-failure

I'm having some weird issues with my computer that I'd be hugely appreciative if someone can help me troubleshoot.

Recently, my HTPC will start fine, then after 20-30 minutes it will freeze up and reboot.  At this point, it will present me with a "reboot and select proper boot device" message.  The bios sees the hard drive, but none of the typical routine for fixing a messed up MBR works because there is no evidence that the drive ever had a valid windows partition on it.

So now for the weird part, if I unplug the computer for a few hours and turn it back on, it starts like normal (except for asking me to boot into safe mode since it shut down improperly last time).  Turning the computer off does nothing, it has to be physically unplugged from my power conditioner.

After 20-30 minutes it will again reboot and not be able to find the boot device.  I pulled the hard drive out and put it in another computer, and there are absolutely no problems with it.

What on earth is happening here?  I'm guessing it's a motherboard or power supply issue, but I'm not really sure where to go from here in terms of diagnosing and fixing the specific issue.

As an aside, before this was happening I was having a potentially related issue.  I have it connected via HDMI to a projector, and I had times where, when coming out of sleep, the video would not initialize (which I chalked up to the horrible HDMI standard and handshake issues).  The only remedy for this was, again, unplug the entire system for a few hours and plug it back in.

Comment: Have you monitored your temps? I have seen this happen when the hard drive over heats.

Comment: Is your heatsink/fan on the cpu clean or does it have gobs of dust on it?  How old and what brand is the power supply?

Comment: @AthomSfere Actually, I haven't monitored my temps.  I'll check the next time I can start it up.

Comment: @cybernard I am using a SilverStone SG08 case and it came with a stock power supply (80 Plus bronze certified, 600W).  I didn't notice a bunch of dust on the heatsink when I checked just now.

Comment: Do you know the make and model of your motherboard?

Comment: @cybernard [ASRock Z68M-ITX/HT](http://www.asrock.com/mb/overview.asp?Model=Z68M-ITX/HT)